# Centering title does not work (wordpress theme)

Tags: css, wordpress, title, centering

I am modifying a free Wordpress theme. I am almost done but I still have a silly problem with this code :

```
<div class="page-header">
   <h1 class="page-title">MyTitle</h1>
</div>
```

What are the possibilities why I can not center the page title ?

I have tried these 2 things but none is OK:

```
.page-header {text-align: center}
.page-title {text-align: center}
```

I am selecting the right component since `display: none` works.

Answer (score 0):

your written css is good, but I think your css is not overwriting existing css of the theme.

Please put this css on: Dashboard->Appearance->Customize->Additional CSS

.page-header {text-align: center !important}

Answer (score 0):

```
.page-header, .page-title {
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

try this text-align if it works

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
.page-header, .page-title {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers.

Yes my css is overwritting the existing one. "display: none" works for example.

I have tried :

```
.page-header, .page-title {
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

and this :

```
.page-header, .page-title {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

... without any success.

The only coding that makes the title moving is:

```
.page-title {
    margin-left: **400px**; 
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

... but not nice at all of course.

Does that ring the bell of other solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
h1.page-title {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Albano,
It works perfectly... that is the good combination indeed. Bye, Xavier